# wrapAll() doesn't work for the first inserted data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to wrap `<p>` and `<span>` together into a div. After inserting the first data, `wrapAll()` didn't work. But when I have entered second data, `wrapAll()` was worked for the first data not for the second data. I want to add wrap along with `<p>` and `<span>` tag.

```js
var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
var button = document.getElementById("button");


// with enter press button
textbox.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
       if(e.shiftKey) {
        }else {
            chatbox(e);
        }
    }
});

function chatbox(e) {
   var newMessage = document.createElement("p");
   newMessage.setAttribute('class', 'list');
   $( ".list, .c-hour" ).wrapAll( "<div class='new'></div>" );
   
   var hour = document.createElement("span");
   hour.setAttribute('class', 'c-hour');
   var d = new Date();
   var n = d.getHours();
   var m = d.getMinutes();
   hour.innerHTML = n + ":" + m;
   messages.appendChild(hour);
   
   newMessage.innerHTML = textbox.value;
   messages.appendChild(newMessage);
   textbox.value = "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="chat-area">
      <ul id ="messages"></ul>
   </div>
   <textarea id="textbox" type="text" placeholder="shout"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: `$( ".list, .c-hour" )` is only going to find elements in the DOM.  At the point in your logic you execute this statement, the `newMessage` is not in the DOM, and `hour` doesn't exist yet at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `$( ".list, .c-hour" ).wrapAll( "<div class='new'></div>" );` after you add the created elements to the document.

So it should be put after `messages.appendChild(newMessage);` like

```
function chatbox(e) {
  var newMessage = document.createElement("p");
  newMessage.setAttribute('class', 'list');

  var hour = document.createElement("span");
  hour.setAttribute('class', 'c-hour');
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getHours();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  hour.innerHTML = n + ":" + m;
  messages.appendChild(hour);

  newMessage.innerHTML = textbox.value;
  messages.appendChild(newMessage);

  $(newMessage).wrapAll( "<div class='new'></div>" );
  $(hour).wrapAll( "<div class='new'></div>" );
  textbox.value = "";
}
```

Comment: If i put `$( ".list, .c-hour" )` after `messages.appendChild(newMessage);` , It's create another wrapper after second submission

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I want to wrap `<p>` and `<span>` together into a div. Means after each submission one wrapper need to be create along with `<p>` and `<span>`. But above code are creating multiple wrapper.